# Rails 2 Delayed_job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am working on rails 2 application where i need to send mail in background job.
I have Notifier model and from controller I call a model method to send mail.
I call that method **Notifier.deliver_method_name(params)** before using delayed job and after creating I use it **Notifier.delay.deliver_method_name(params)**.

Now my question arise

1) Should I need to start the rake jobs:work to send mail in background in development and if yes should I run it every time I start server?
2) what do I need to do on production should I run rake jobs:work for the first time ?
3) Is that right if any error occurs then only there is a entry in delayed job if it is successful then there is no entry in delayed_job table.

I follow the below link

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Should I need to start the rake jobs:work to send mail in background in development and if yes should I run it every time I start server?

Yes you have to start rake task separately.

`Workers can be running on any computer, as long as they have access to the database and their clock is in sync. Keep in mind that each worker will check the database at least every 5 seconds.`

2) what do I need to do on production should I run rake jobs:work for the first time ?

Yes you have to with `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` But I suggest you stop and start this at every deployment to take changes done.

3) Is that right if any error occurs then only there is a entry in delayed job if it is successful then there is no entry in delayed_job table.

No it's completely depends on your configuration

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
```

Comment: for 2nd question I need to run RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start OR rake jobs:work If both which one to first?

Comment: for 3rd case there is no delayed_job_config.rb file in initializers folder then what would be happend?
Is it advisable to create manually that file?

Comment: Both can be used but I used `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

Comment: I have this in my initialize `# This initializer was added because v2.0.2 of DelayedJob wouldn't
# initialize the Delayed::Job class when installed as a gem.
Delayed::Worker.guess_backend` As per doc there is possibility of configuration. So I suggest you to create a initialize file and configure plugin as you want